# Opening Amazon Lambda API Gateway to public use

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I was playing around with Amazon Lambda, and created a super simple REST API endpoint. The lambda function is connected to an AWS API Gateway, which even gives me back an URL that I should supposedly be able to use to execute my lambda function.

However, even though I set "Authorization" to "None", and "Api Key" to "None required", it seems like a general end-user would still be unable to directly execute my lambda function, as I am getting a `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` message when just pasting the execution URL into my browser.

When I google the error, it seems like it has to do with some kind of IAM permissions. However, I clearly set authorization to "None", not "AWS IAM". I don't *want* to determine some kind of specific access: Since I'm playing around, I just want to be able to send the link to some friends, and that they can use it without first having to put together some complex authorization request.

This confuses me - How am I supposed to make my function accessible?

Comment: You have to deploy the API after each modification you are making, otherwise the changes wont take effect.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I did

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-authentication-token-errors/) it suggests to check:

- Execution URL must be correct.
- Request is not signed if AIM is used.

Note: Any changes needs re-deploy of the API.